# How to loop through all columns and rows in 2 dataframes within existing R function

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying to calculate Brier scores for participants who have answered multiple questions in a survey about the likelihood of different events occurring.

I'm using the existing Brierscore function in R and everything works perfectly when I am only interested in a single column (i.e. answers for all participants for 1 question. I cannot work out how to write a loop to cycle through all columns (questions).

I have 2 dataframes:

1. correct_answers, contains 1 and 0 to indicate whether event happened
2. forecast, participants forecasts on whether something will happen on 0-1 scale.

I have tried multiple for loop structures, and using a for loop for each dataframe. The example below seems closest to what I need but is still not correct. I am trying to work out if my syntax is wrong or if I cannot loop using these types of functions.

This works:

```
Brier_scores_all_questions <- brierscore(correct_answer$Election_Outcome ~ forecast$Election_Outcome, forecast, decomp = FALSE, bounds = c(0,2),
                         reverse = FALSE, wt = NULL)
```

This is one of the loops I have tried:

```
for(i in 1:ncol) { 

Brier_scores_all_questions <- brierscore(correct_answer$[[i]] ~ forecast$[[i]], forecast, decomp = FALSE, bounds = c(0,2),
                         reverse = FALSE, wt = NULL)

} # close loop
```

Ideally I would like a matrix with the Brier scores for each participant (rows) and question (columns). Below is the error message I get:

> for(i in 2:ncol) { 
>   + 
>   + Brier_scores_all_questions <- brierscore(df_ans_base$[[i]] ~ df_base$[[i]], 
>   Error: unexpected '[[' in:
>   "
>   Brier_scores_all_questions <- brierscore(df_ans_base$[["
>                            df_base,decomp = FALSE, bounds = c(0,2),
>   Error: unexpected ',' in "                         df_base,"
>                            reverse = FALSE, wt = NULL)
>   Error: unexpected ',' in "                         reverse = FALSE,"
>
> } 
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}

Answer (score 0):

I believe your loop structure is correct, but you have a mistake in how you're indexing into the dataframe. The `$` operator and the `[]` are redundant in this case. For instance, let's imagine `Election_Outcome` is the 2nd column in `forecast`. Then you can select that column specifically by either using `forecast$Election_Outcome` or `forecast[,2]`. When you use `[,2]`, you're asking for all rows and column 2. So in your loop you should do something like `forecast[,i]`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works to an extent but overwrites the previous column. I want to write out a matrix and hoped the code below would do the trick.                                  for(i in 1:3) { 

Brier_scores_all_questions[,i] <- brierscore(df_ans_base[,i] ~ df_base[,i], decomp = FALSE, bounds = c(0,2), 
                                         reverse = FALSE, wt = NULL)

} 
I have a feeling I'm using syntax that would work in Matlab but I can't see how to adjust it here. Perhaps you can spot something missing?

Comment: What is the structure of `Brier_scores_all_questions`? Just at a brief glance your syntax looks alright but that depends on what that data structure looks like.

Comment: Wait I solved it! Need to define the matrix outside the loop!                                                  Brier_scores_all_questions <- matrix(ncol=5, nrow=42)
Thanks again, wouldn't have solved it for ages without your help.